# How can I get the file reader to not have the exception?

Tags: java, arraylist, maps, bufferedreader, ioexception

The assignment is to read each word of the file and count the frequency of each word using a map. Then to organize them using the given method sortByValue(Map map). I am confused as to how to get the file to read in correctly and assign integer values to the String keys. Help?

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class WordFrequency {
     public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {

     File textFile = new File("book.txt"); 
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
     TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
     String currentLine; 
     while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         currentLine = currentLine.toLowerCase();


     }

     StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentLine, " \t\n\r\f.,;:!?'");

     while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
         final String currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken(); Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord);
         if (frequency == null) { frequency = 0; } frequencyMap.put(currentWord,frequency + 1);

     }
     ArrayList map;
     map = sortByValue(frequencyMap);

     for(int i= 0; i < 20; i++)
         System.out.println(map.get(i));

     }

// Sort a map with its values in ascending order
public static ArrayList < Map . Entry > sortByValue ( Map map )
{
ArrayList < Map . Entry > a = new ArrayList ( map . entrySet () );
// sort by providing my own comparator
Collections . sort (a , new Comparator ()
{
public int compare ( Object o1 , Object o2 )
{
Map . Entry e1 = ( Map . Entry ) o1 ;
Map . Entry e2 = ( Map . Entry ) o2 ;
return (( Comparable ) e1 . getValue () ). compareTo ( e2 . getValue () ) ;
}
}) ;
return a;
}


 }
```

The IOException is

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at WordFrequency.main(WordFrequency.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {`

When this loop exits, `currrentLine` will be `null`, this was the requirement of the loop.

What you should consider doing is moving the processing of `currentLine` within the `while` loop you are using to read the file...

For example...

```
while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     currentLine = currentLine.toLowerCase();
     StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentLine, " \t\n\r\f.,;:!?'");

     while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
         final String currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
         Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord);
         if (frequency == null) { 
             frequency = 0; 
         } 
         frequencyMap.put(currentWord,frequency + 1);
     }

 }
```

Comment: That got rid of the exception, but for some reason now it doesn't output anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. Have you tried outputting the size of the `frequencyMap` after you've finished reading the file

Comment: part of the assignment is to print the 20 most frequent and least frequent words. I tried using the a for each loop but there is a type mismatch from Map.Entry to Object. Why does this not work?

Comment: You could try changing `ArrayList map;` to `ArrayList<Map.Entry> map;`

Comment: Sorry, the code actually did output it just took a while. But when reading the file using specified delimiters it sometimes link two words together and It wont allow me to delimit quote marks. Any way to fix this? (the file is a sherlock holmes book so the code kinda takes a while to compile)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     currentLine = currentLine.toLowerCase();
 }
```

You basically just go through the file until the end. Then null is saved in currentLine and you call the Tokenizer with null ---> NullPointerException.

Add a new variable:

```
 String text = "";
 while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     text += currentLine.toLowerCase();
 }
```

Then use `text` for the Tokenizer.

Comment: That got rid of the exception, but for some reason now it doesn't output anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another String to get `currentLine` before it become null, e.g. see `entireText` below:

```
package org.fuzzyanalysis.demo;


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordFrequency {

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {

         File textFile = new File("book.txt"); 
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
         TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
         String currentLine; 
         String entireText = "";
         while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

             currentLine = currentLine.toLowerCase();            
             entireText += currentLine;

         }

         StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(entireText, " \t\n\r\f.,;:!?'");

         while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
             final String currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken(); Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord);
             if (frequency == null) { frequency = 0; } frequencyMap.put(currentWord,frequency + 1);

         }
         ArrayList map;
         map = sortByValue(frequencyMap);

         for(int i= 0; i < 20; i++)
             System.out.println(map.get(i));

         }

    // Sort a map with its values in ascending order
    public static ArrayList < Map . Entry > sortByValue ( Map map )
    {
        ArrayList < Map . Entry > a = new ArrayList ( map . entrySet () );
        // sort by providing my own comparator
        Collections . sort (a , new Comparator ()
        {
            public int compare ( Object o1 , Object o2 )
            {
                Map . Entry e1 = ( Map . Entry ) o1 ;
                Map . Entry e2 = ( Map . Entry ) o2 ;
                return (( Comparable ) e1 . getValue () ). compareTo ( e2 . getValue () ) ;
            }
        }) ;
    return a;
    }


}
```

Comment: That got rid of the exception, but for some reason now it doesn't output anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you use a file called "book.txt" in the same directory as your project, then put some words into it.  I got the following output when using "book.txt" as a file that contains the words "this is a book ahha":  a=1
ahha=1
book=1
is=1
this=1